# Change values in object java

Tags: java

I have 2 objects in Java, person1 and person2. With a event button in the code I say that person2 = person1, then I need to change the age of person 1 without change person2.

```
Person objperson1 = new Person();
objperson1.setAge(30);
Person objperson2 = new Person();
objperson2 = objperson1;
objperson1.setAge(40);
System.out.println(objperson2.getAge()); //console print 40. I need it print 30
```

Comment: try cloning the Object

Comment: `objperson2 = objperson1;` - Now you no longer have two objects, but only one.

Comment: implement cloneable interface

Comment: or a decent copy, instead of assignment.  but first step: question your logic: "I say that person2 = person1, then I need to change the age of person 1 without change person2." how is this supposed to make sense?

Comment: @Stultuske obviously this is his first time in OOPs

Comment: @Lokesh possible, but having a decent grasp and understanding of logic is a requirement to be able to start programming, seeing as he's already doing that .. If I thought the problem was (just) with his OO skills, I would question the use of storing an 'age' for a person

Comment: @Stultuske yea logic should be clear first !!.

Comment: @Stultuske the class Person is just a example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
 public class Demo {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws CloneNotSupportedException{

    Person p1=new Person();
    p1.setAge(30);


    Person p2 = (Person) p1.clone();
    p1.setAge(40);
    System.out.println(p2.getAge());//30

    }
    }

    class Person implements Cloneable{

    private int age;

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return (Person)super.clone();  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`objperson1` and `objperson2` are two reference variables pointing to the same Person object.

If you want a copy of `objperson1` you could use:

```
 Person objperson2 = (Person) objperson1.clone();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this stems from a misunderstanding on what's happening in Java. When you say `objperson2 = objperson1;`, you're telling it to assign the name `objperson2` to point to the object that `objperson1` is referencing.  So it's like assigning another name to the same thing. In other words, let's say your name (`objperson1`) was Patrick. If I say "I'm going to call you Pat from now on" (`objperson2=objperson1`), and I then say "Pat, pass me the salt", I would expect you to pass me the salt, because both names point to you. So you need to create two different objects (like having two different people) with two different names.

To do a copy like this, you'd be looking at preforming a "deep copy". The question should be, "Is this really necessary for you to do?" It's relatively rare to need to do this, so I would question your implementation and reconsider how you're coding the problem.

Answer (score 0):

implement clone to your object

```
 public class Person implements Cloneable{

    private String age;
    public Person(){
    }
    public void setStr(String age){
        this.age = age;
    }
    protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return super.clone();
    }
}
```

Clone object

```
Person per = new Person();

Person delTemp = (Person ) per.clone();
```

Answer (score 0):

Year code:

```
objperson2 = objperson1;
```

means that `objperson2` variable has link on `objperson1` object now. In your case you need to make a copy of `objperson1` and apply it to `objperson2` variable. You can do it like this:

```
objperson2 = objperson1.clone();
```

But keep in mind that you must to implement clone mechanism for custom object. Example:

```
public class Person implements Cloneable {

    private int age;

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public Person clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        Person copy = new Person();
        copy.age = this.age; // (example deep clone for custom properties) or just use Person copy = super.clone();

        return copy;
    }
}
```

Use:

```
Person objperson1 = new Person();
        objperson1.setAge(30);        
        Person objperson2 = objperson1.clone();
        objperson1.setAge(40);
        System.out.println(objperson2.getAge());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use your bean method too like :

```
Person objperson1 = new Person();
objperson1.setAge(30);
Person objperson2 = new Person();
objperson2.setAge(objperson1.getAge()); // <= With the getter and setter method
objperson1.setAge(40);
System.out.println(objperson2.getAge());
```

In this case you only get the value and save independence of your two objects.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see what happens in Java.

```
// Create a new Person object
// and let the variable objperson1 refer to it
Person objperson1 = new Person();

// Call the method setAge(int) on the object previously created
objperson1.setAge(30);

// Create another Person object
// and let the variable objperson2 refer to it
Person objperson2 = new Person();

// Let the variable objperson2 refer to the object objperson1
// is referring to.
// The reference to the Person objperson2 was referring to
// HAS NO LONGER A REFERENCE TO IT. You can never reach that object again.
objperson2 = objperson1;

// Setting the age on objperson1 reflects a change in objperson2, because
// they refer to the very same object
objperson1.setAge(40);
```

The misconception here is propably what you think that `var1 = var2` actually clones it or something.

There is a way to clone your object, as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46724311/507738) stated.

However, question is whether you have to clone two objects. You can just create two objects like this:

```
Person alan = new Person(30);
Person boris = new Person(30);

boris.setAge(40);
```

*PS: Using `clone()` and implementing the `Cloneable` interface is [discouraged in Effective Java](http://www.artima.com/intv/bloch13.html).*

Answer (score 0):

As your variables type is an object variable, and your goal is to change the variables' parameters only,  `objperson2 = objperson1;`   is a bad code. If it's not a must program code that you need to solve, I would suggest deleting that line of code, then alter it by

```
    objperson2.setAge(objperson1.getAge());
    objperson1.setAge(parameter);
```

If `objperson2 = objperson1;` is a must-have line, then there's no way to change one parameter without changing the other. In my code, both `objperson1` and `objperson2` are actually the same since their parameters are identical, but still changeable. Otherwise, you should use Clone.